# MySQL WHERE Clause - Age Greater/Less than

Tags: mysql

I have the following SELECT that I can't get to work:

```
SELECT COUNT(userid) FROM login 
WHERE 17 < YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL TO_DAYS(profile_birthdate) DAY) 
AND 46 > YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL TO_DAYS(profile_birthdate) DAY);
```

The following works fine so I know the YEAR equation is sound:

```
SELECT YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL TO_DAYS(profile_birthdate) DAY)) 
AS age FROM login;
```

Just wondering how to get the top one to work; also, is there a similar way then repeating the YEAR equation twice?

thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just typo. You have missed close brackets.

```
SELECT COUNT(userid) FROM login 
WHERE 17 < YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL TO_DAYS(profile_birthdate) DAY)) 
    AND 46 > YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL TO_DAYS(profile_birthdate) DAY));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try BETWEEN in this Query and don't forget the the missing close ")"

```
SELECT COUNT(userid) FROM login 
WHERE YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL TO_DAYS(profile_birthdate) DAY)) BETWEEN 17 AND 46
```

Comment: Right! Actually I just noticed he wanted to get below 17 and greater 46 so BETWEEN will not work for him. haha. but yeah. it was the missing ")" causes the query not to work for him. thanks for the comment.